# Importação de Dados

Tags: c#, oracle, algoritmo-de-busca, importação

Olá, gostaria de saber como eu pego um valor do meu banco de dados e levo para um campo "automaticamente". Por exemplo, na imagem a abaixo, eu quero que neste campo marcado vá uma informação que já está salva em meu banco de dados. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para busca-lá e coloca-lá neste campo, se for possível fazer isso. Estou usando visual studio(c#) e sql developer(Oracle).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na classe eu coloquei isso:

```
public OracleDataReader ListarUs()
{
    string strQuery = "SELECT MAX(COD_FUNCIONARIO) COD_FUNCIONARIO FROM FUNCIONARIO WHERE USUARIO='"+ _usuario+"'";
    clnBancoDados ObjBancoDados = new clnBancoDados();
    return ObjBancoDados.RetornaDataReader(strQuery);
}
```

mas não acontece nada.

Comment: No `onLoad` do form você faz o select no banco e coloca o valor que quiser no seu `TextBox`.

Comment: Voce quer que quando voce aperte "salvar" ele mostre o codigo gerado para o funcionário na base, isso?

Comment: Você quer que mostre o próximo ID que será deste novo funcionário, certo? Por exemplo, o último funcionário têm o ID 23, o próximo cadastro teria o ID 24, então apresentaria o Cód Funcionário 24 direto nesse `TextBox`. Seria isso?

Comment: Na verdade eu já tenho esse ID. Eu tenho uma tela de login, e queria que nesse campo, fosse o ID do funcionário (que já está cadastrado e que tem um ID) que estivesse logado no sistema.

Comment: Enzo, mostre o código do que vc já fez. Senão fica parecendo que vc quer que façamos pra vc.

Comment: @enzo Tente me explicar melhor seu problema: **o que você precisa é pegar o Id do funcionário logado e colocar no textbox?** Estou certo?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Como existe mais de um Funcionário, eu teria que "identificar" qual desses estaria logado, para importar o seu Id na textbox. Eu quero importar o Id, assim que eu abrisse o formulário(ele já abrir o formulário com o campo preenchido).

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo de CRUD de Usuario

---

Conexao no banco

```
  using System.Configuration;
  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

  namespace PrjGpaci
  {
 class sisBdConn
  {
    protected MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PrjGpaci.Properties.Settings.gpaciConnectionString1"].ToString());

    protected bool abrir()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex) { return false; }
    }

    protected bool fechar()
    {
        try
        {

            conn.Clone();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex) { return false; }
    }
}
}
```

---

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Data;
  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

  namespace PrjGpaci
  {
  class sisBdUsr:sisBdConn
  {


    /// <summary>
    /// Cadastra o usuario
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="r"> Classe Usr</param>
    /// <returns>  verdadeiro se cadastrou ou falso se não cadastrou </returns>
    public bool cadUsr(Usr r)
    {
        try
        {

            abrir();

            string strquery = "INSERT INTO usr (id,psw,nome,tipo) VALUES (@id,@psw,@nome,@tipo)";
            MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand(strquery, conn);

            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",r.Id);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@psw",r.Psw);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome",r.Nome);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", r.Tipo);

            comand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            fechar();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Atualiza as informaçoes do usuario
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="r"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool upUsr(Usr r)
    {
        try
        {
            abrir();

            string strquery = "UPDATE usr SET id =@id,psw =@psw,nome =@nome,tipo = @tipo WHERE codu = @codu";
            MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand(strquery, conn);

            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", r.Id);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@psw", r.Psw);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", r.Nome);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", r.Tipo);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codu", r.Cod);

            comand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            fechar();                
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Consulta para login
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">id</param>
    /// <param name="psw">senha</param>
    /// <returns> retorna classe usr null se não encontrar ou reotna usr com os dados do usr</returns>  
    public Usr login(string id, string psw)
    {
        try
        {
            Usr u = null;
            abrir();
            string strquery = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE Id LIKE @id AND Psw LIKE @psw";
            MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand(strquery, conn);

            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@psw", psw);

            MySqlDataReader ler = comand.ExecuteReader();

                while (ler.Read())
                {
                    u = new Usr();
                    u.Cod = Convert.ToInt32(ler["codu"]);
                    u.Id = ler["id"].ToString();
                    u.Psw = ler["psw"].ToString();
                    u.Nome = ler["nome"].ToString();
                    u.Tipo = Convert.ToInt32(ler["tipo"]);
                    fechar();
                    return u;

                }


            fechar();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// busca todos os usuario
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>retorna dataset</returns>
    public DataSet dataUsr()
    {
        try
        {
            abrir();
            string strquery = "SELECT codu ,id ,psw,nome,tipo FROM usr";

            MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand(strquery, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(comand);
            da.Fill(ds);
            fechar();


            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
            throw;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pesquisa por codigo
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cod"></param>
    /// <returns>retorna dataset</returns>
    public DataSet dataUsr(int cod)
    {
        try
        {
            abrir();
            string strquery = "SELECT codu ,id ,psw,nome,tipo FROM usr WHERE codu = @cod";

            MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand(strquery, conn);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod",cod);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(comand);
            da.Fill(ds, "tbUsuario");
            fechar();


            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
            throw;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pesquisa por id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns>retorna dataset</returns>
    public DataSet dataUsr(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            abrir();
            string strquery = "SELECT codu ,id ,psw,nome,tipo FROM usr WHERE id LIKE @id";

            MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand(strquery, conn);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(comand);
            da.Fill(ds);
            fechar();
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
            throw;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pesquisa por nome
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nome"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public DataSet pesqNome(string nome)
    {
        try
        {
            abrir();
            string strquery = "SELECT codu ,id ,psw,nome,tipo FROM usr WHERE nome LIKE @nome";

            MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand(strquery, conn);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(comand);
            da.Fill(ds);
            fechar();
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
            throw;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pesquisa o id exato do usario e retorna verdadeiro ou falso
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool pesqIdExiste(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            abrir();
            string strquery = "SELECT codu ,id ,psw,nome,tipo FROM usr WHERE id = @id";

            MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand(strquery, conn);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

            MySqlDataReader ler = comand.ExecuteReader();
            while (ler.Read())
            {

                fechar();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
            throw;
        }

    }


    public bool deletaUsr(int cod)
    {
        try
        {
            abrir();
            string strquery = "DELETE FROM usr WHERE CodU = @codu";

            MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand(strquery, conn);
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codu", cod);
            comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;

        }
        catch (MySqlException)
        {
            return false;
            throw;
        }

    }
}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

No Construtor da sua Classe Form faça a consulta no BD e seta o código do funcionário para o campo.

```
 //construtor do form.
public CadastroLogin(){

    SetCodigoFuncionario();
}



private SetCodigoFuncionario(){

   try{
     OracleDataReader = dr = ListarUs();
     txtCodigoFuncionario.Text = dr["COD_FUNCIONARIO"].ToString();
  }catch(Exception e){
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}

}
```

Isso considerando que sua query esteja executando como esperado.
Obs. Nao fiz o codigo no VS, entao a sintaxe pode nao estar 100%